# importing django.db models messes up my datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a code which look like this:-

```
print datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
```

It prints out

```
2016-10-13_03:19:48
```

... which is correct for me.

But somehow, when i import the django.db module, it messes up my time:-

```
from django.db import models
print datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
```

... gives me this:-

```
2016-10-13_17:19:48
```

Can someone help me understsand what's the magic behind? 
And how can I fix this so that whenever i call datetime, it gives me the first result:-

```
2016-10-13_03:19:48
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you mean first result? *Time flies*...looks like you want a 12 hour format instead of 24?

Comment: it is actually 3am now, so the first script (without importing django.db) is giving me the correct output. But when i did an import on django.db, datetime seems to be .... incorrect. I'm guessing it must be the settings of the django that changes something?

Comment: Try `from django.utils import timezone` and `timezone.now` providing you have the right configurations in your settings.py file. Then do `timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @lionel319 Yes, that is very likely. Confirm that your `TIME_ZONE` setting is properly setup.

Comment: @JackEvans I followed your instructions, and it prints out the same incorrect time. so ...... any idea how I can print out the correct time even when I import Django.db?